# RSpec testing with stripe-ruby-mock

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, rspec, stripe-payments

If a Stripe charge is successful, and the posted info passes the validations, the user should be redirected to the sold_url.

```
def create

    customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
        :email        => params[:stripeEmail],
        :card         => params[:stripeToken],
    )
    charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
        :customer     => customer.id,
        :amount       => @price * 100,
    )

    if charge["paid"]
      @product.update(status: "sold",
                      email:      params[:stripeEmail],
                      first_name: params[:first_name],
                      last_name:  params[:last_name])
      @product.update_attribute(:agreed_to_terms, 1)
      redirect_to :back
    else
      @product.update_attribute(:status, "for_sale")
    end
```

If it fails, it should be redirected `:back` to the url of the product it failed to buy.

```
rescue Stripe::CardError => e
  flash[:error] = e.message
  redirect_to :back
end
```

I am trying to mock the transaction with stripe-ruby-mock.

```
RSpec.describe 'checkout page', :type => :request do

  let(:stripe_helper) { StripeMock.create_test_helper }
  before { StripeMock.start }
  after { StripeMock.stop }

    it 'redirects back if there is missing info' do
    post "/product/1", {:first_name => "john", :last_name => "doe",
     :stripeEmail => "johndoe@doe.com"}, {:referer => '/product/1'}
    expect(response).to redirect_to '/product/1'
  end

  it 'successfully processes a charge' do
    post "/product/1", {:first_name => "john",
                     :last_name => "doe",
                     :stripeEmail => "johndoe@doe.com",
                     :stripeToken => stripe_helper.generate_card_token,
                     :agreed_to_terms => 1},
                    {:referer => '/product/1'}
    expect(response).to redirect_to 'sold_url'
  end
```

But it responds that the test with missing info is being redirected to the sold_url.

```
Failures:

  1) checkout page redirects back if there is missing info
     Failure/Error: expect(response).to redirect_to '/product/1'
       Expected response to be a redirect to <http://www.example.com/product/1> but was a redirect to <http://www.example.com/sold>.
       Expected "http://www.example.com/product/1" to be === "http://www.example.com/sold".
```

Is it my controller or my test that is misbehaving?

Comment: What Stripe API version are you using?

Comment: I'm using Stripe Custom Checkout @mindeavor 2015-01-11